# How to lock a MySQL row and release later in application context

Tags: mysql, spring, transactions, jdbctemplate

I'm pretty aware of the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` approach, but it does work when updating later via the same connection.
However put in an application context, this is not much the case, as database manager uses a pool of connections. I'd like to get records from DB and they become locked in the Controller below, work on them while no other Controller can read them or update them, and when finished work update them and release the lock. How to do that?

I'm using Spring JDBCTemplate and have these several classes:

ItemDao:

```
@Service
public class ItemDao extends AppDao {

    // this is supposed to lock the row
    public UserItems getItemsForUpdate(long userId) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from tbl_items where ownerId = ?", new UserItemsRowMapper(), userId);
    }

    public void updateItems(UserItems items) {

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(items);
            oos.close();
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

            jdbcTemplate.update("update tbl_items set data = ? where id = ?", new Object[] { data, items.getId() });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Web endpoint handler:

```
@Controller
public class EnergyFillHandler extends BaseItemsUpdatedHandler<EnergyFillRequest> {

    @RequestMapping(value="/energyFill", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List<BaseResponse> handle(@RequestBody EnergyFillRequest json) {

        UserItems items = itemDao.getItems(u.getId());

        ... do something; if someone else calls getItems 
        he needs to be blocked at this point

        itemDao.updateItems(userItems);

        ... items are now released and anyone can read and obtain lock on them
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not missing anything obvious here, make your service `@Transactional` and set the appropriate isolation level. Don't know your scenario, but I think you can use `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE`.

Comment: Actually, you need to make sure that this code: `UserItems items = itemDao.getItems(u.getId()); itemDao.updateItems(userItems);` is wrapped in a single `SERIALIZABLE` transaction.

Comment: ok, great , but all this actions happen in the EnergyFillHandler that is an exposed web endpoint, it has no access to any transactional managers and whatsoever because they have their place at the DAOs

Comment: But it has access to the dao. What stops you to make your dao transactional?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. In EnergyFillHandler I call two methods of the DAO - one that obtains results, then it does some work, and then it calls another method of the DAO that updates what EnergyFillHandler has done. The question is how am I supposed to make this transactional, since the actual work happens outside the DAO. If you post some examples, I would be grateful

Comment: What's being done in this "... do something; if someone else calls getItems he needs to be blocked at this point"?

Comment: well, some actions, just like updating the items and stuff. doesn't matter

Comment: I think it does. If you can move that stuff inside dao, you could make that whole block of code transactional.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I know. That's the whole point :) The question is how to do this preserving the AOP aspect - the handler does business logic that is none of the DAO's business - and vice versa. The question is how to ensure transactional flow in the above scenario

Comment: If you want to have this kind of locking at database level, but do the "atomic" operation in two separate operations then you can't.

Comment: it should be possible. Basically it's opening a single connection and begin a transaction and keeping it open before you do your work and then commit. I just wonder how is this done in Spring JDBC. Thank you

Comment: Yes, but what you say is exactly what I was saying, it's just a matter of boundaries (transactional boundaries at Java code level). You could do this in your controller `handle()` method: manually (programmatically) start a transaction before `itemDao.getItems` and then manually handle the end of the transaction. But whatever option you choose (either with `@Transactional` or manually), you need the code between `itemDao.getItems` and `itemDao.updateItems` to be, at Java code level (the database doesn't care if you do a Fibonacci computation there, for example), in a transactional block.

Comment: About programmatic management of transactions in Spring you can read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-programmatic). I can provide some code, if you like, but you need to understand first that, if you need this level of locking at database row level, you need to have a transaction that will lock those rows during all the calls present in your controller between `itemDao.getItems` and `itemDao.updateItems` (both those call included, as well). In my opinion, I don't think there is another option.

Comment: I would agree here with Andrei, if you are struggling to reconcile what your current code is doing with what he is suggesting perhaps the code is not separated by concerns well enough. I would suggest pushing `getItems` and `updateItems` as well as the code in between either into the `itemDao` or into an intermediate service layer that  can be transactional.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like its a flavor of the [readers-writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) which is extended to transactions from the database. I would create a SQL-transactional class which is primarily responsible for the CRUD operations with your database. I would then have a flag which could be locked and released in a very similar way to mutex locks, this way you are able to ensure that no two concurrent processes are in their critical section (performing an UPDATE or INSERT into the DB) at the same time.

I also believe there is a [readers-writers lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock) which specifically deals with controlling access to a shared resource, which might be of interest to you.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, if you want/need the locking at the database rows level for the time some Java code is being executed, then that piece of Java code needs to be surrounded by a transactional boundary. If you do this by creating a new method in a service class, for example, and in that method you place all the Java code that needs to "lock" those rows OR if you do it manually, by programmatic transactions, directly in the controller code it's up to you. But, in my opinion, you need to have this level of transactional demarcation to be able to "lock" the databse. Depending on how strict you want to be with the locking, you can try starting with SERIALIZABLE where the rows are locked for reading and writing and every operation is done in a serializable way, one after the other.